# Mongoose error const err = new MongooseError(message); - buffering timed out

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-web-server

I am trying to use node.js with MongoDB using Mongoose, but damn I am stuck in the same error for last week, it keeps giving the same error:

[image]

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/newDB", { useNewUrlParser: true ,  useUnifiedTopology: true 
 });

console.log("Connected")


//SCHEMA

const DBSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({name : String,anything : String})


const DaB= mongoose.model("Working",DBSchema)


const db=new DaB({name:"user",anything:"Some text"})

db.save();
```

I have tried various ways to fix it ,but it isnt fixing

Comment: Are you able to connect to mongo outside the code? and which version of mongoose are you using?

Comment: Don't use `localhost`, use `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @MostafaFakhraei Thank you for responding . Yes I am able to use mongo outside the code in the terminal using mongo shell. I am using the version "6.8.3" of mongoose

Comment: @robertklep THANKSS! A lot man ,it worked.It Worked by replacing Local host  by 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Don't use localhost, use 127.0.0.1.(Source - @robertklep)